# Discord doesn't update banner image via API

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to update my server banner programmatically.

It doesn't throw an error, and returns the guild object (which according to [the docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#modify-guild) means success).

But the banner does not change.

I wonder if this is due to the format of the options supplied to the data? But I cannot find what the proper format is supposed to be, either on the docs for discord or the npm module.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import promises from 'fs/promises';
import { REST } from '@discordjs/rest';
import { Routes } from 'discord-api-types/v10';
import { glob } from 'glob';


const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);

(async () => {
    try {

        //get guild data
        let guild = await rest.get(Routes.guild(process.env.DISCORD_GUILD_ID));
        console.log('Got guild "'+ guild.name +'"');
        let guildHasBanner = guild.features.includes('BANNER');
        console.log('Guild has banner: ', guildHasBanner, guild.banner);
        if (!guildHasBanner) throw 'Guild does not have access to banner feature';

        //get banner
        let listOfBannerFiles = await glob('_banners/*.png');
        let randomBannerFile = listOfBannerFiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfBannerFiles.length)];
        console.log('setting banner to: ', randomBannerFile);
        let imageData = await loadImage(randomBannerFile);
        
        //update banner
        await rest.patch(Routes.guild(process.env.DISCORD_GUILD_ID), {data: {banner: imageData}});
        console.log('Banner updated successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();

//load image from file and return base64 encoded string
async function loadImage (path) {
    let data = await promises.readFile(path)
    let base64 = data.toString('base64');
    console.log('loaded ', path);
    return `data:image/png;base64,${base64}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `await rest.patch(Routes.guild(process.env.DISCORD_GUILD_ID), {data: {banner: imageData}});`

There is no such property called `data`. Ergo, nothing is happening.

You should read the [documentation](https://discordjs.dev/docs/packages/rest/2.0.1/RequestData:Interface). You want `body`.

---

discord.js uses @discordjs/rest internally. Therefore, if you're struggling with something, it would not be a bad idea to see what discord.js is doing internally. In this case, this is how discord.js patches a banner:

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/e80194e3fb186269e479f0a5a323580103e584c0/packages/discord.js/src/structures/Guild.js#L869

You can see on line 858 `body` is being used—`data` is not present. That would be a hint for you.